# How to ignore the line completely with regex? (lookahead doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex for finding a phone number

```
(([0-9]{3}[-./ ]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-./ ]{0,1}[0-9]{4}))|([(][0-9) ]{4,5}[0-9]{3}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{4})
```

See it in action here - http://regexr.com/3dsbk

My goal is to ignore each result, if its preceding symbol is #

I've tried adding a negative lookahead, like this:

```
(?!#)(([0-9]{3}[-./ ]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-./ ]{0,1}[0-9]{4}))|([(][0-9) ]{4,5}[0-9]{3}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{4})
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is negative lookahead looks … well … ahead. It looks if at, starting from the first position of the _match_ the regex is not matched. You'd want a lookbehind, which Javascript does not have.

Comment: JS is not sophisticated enough to be able to `ignore` anything, let alone a the line. The way to do this is to match the offender, then ignore it or not after it matches something. `([#])?((?:[0-9]{3}[-./ ]?){2}[0-9]{4}|[(][0-9) ]{4,5}[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4})` if capture group 1 matched ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex itself can't help. You need to use some programming logic around the pattern matching. A usual lookbehind replacement is to use an optional group at the pattern start, and then check if the group matched. If it did, the string before your match exists -> we should discard those matches. Else, get them.

```
/(#)?[0-9]{3}[-.\/ ]?[0-9]{3}[-.\/ ]?[0-9]{4}|[(][0-9) ]{4,5}[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uC8lC9/1) that has no value without code below:

```js
var re = /(#)?[0-9]{3}[-.\/ ]?[0-9]{3}[-.\/ ]?[0-9]{4}|[(][0-9) ]{4,5}[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}/g; 
var str = '1012 345 6789\n#1231231231 (only this to be ignored)\nphone 1231231231\n1012.345.6789\n012/345/6789\n555-123-4567    \n+1-(800) 555-2468\n+1-800 555-2468';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   if (!m[1]) {
      res.push(m[0]);
   }
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

You might need to adjust your regex to extract whole words only by adding word boundaries `\b` around the pattern, like `/(#)?\b[0-9]{3}[-.\/ ]?[0-9]{3}[-.\/ ]?[0-9]{4}|[(][0-9) ]{4,5}[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}\b/g`, but that might require further adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

```
([^#](([0-9]{3}[-./ ]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-./ ]{0,1}[0-9]{4}))|([(][0-9) ]{4,5}[0-9]{3}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{4}))
```

Comment: Yeah that \n thing was my mistake. 
However you only said numbers with preceding symbol # must be ignored, so numbers that have # at the end is ok to capture.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the OP's question about preceding. +1

Comment: This captures other symbols too. For example: -800 555-2468

Comment: @VitaliyHayda, does that mean this is not what you are looking for. If so, why was that not specified in your question? The only character you said said you *didn't* want was a **`#`**?

Comment: @VitaliyHayda Javascript regex is not that smart. Javascript has no fancy features like lookbehind or match reset. You'll have to remove it yourself programmatically from the match.

Comment: @KevBot Correct, it is not what I'm looking for. I also said that I'm trying to extract phone numbers. So -800 555-2468 would not be a typical phone number, as well as if there is any other character in front (ex: %800 555-2468)